# Which preposition should I use after “The figures”?

Tags: prepositions, ielts

I have a question about which preposition should I use in this sentence:

*The figures ____ (for/of) train and bicycle use reveal a steady drop in these types of transport.*

I think *of* should be used. But the answer is *for*. Can anyone suggest me why *for* is the correct answer here?

Answer (score 1):

The answer depends on what you intend to communicate, which isn't clear.

"The figures of train and bicycle use" refers to some sort of graphical diagram that promises to discuss train and bicycle usage.

"The figures for train and bicycle use" refers to some non-graphical numbers or calculations about trains and bicycle usage.

Answer (score 0):

> Can anyone suggest me why *for* is the correct answer here?

Propositions vary between languages, it's not a one-to-one mapping.

For example:

It depends on you -> Depende de ti

The preposition "on" is translated as "of" in Spanish.

Moreover, "de" can be "of", "from", "by", "with", "at", and many more.

There isn't an objectively correct answer about prepositions, such as in mathematics 1+2=3, which is correct for everyone.

You simply have to memorize when to use "for".

That said, you could think of the usage as an abbreviation "The figures *for analyzing* train and bicycle use" or "The figures *for tallying* train and bicycle use" or "The figures *for the purposes of counting* train and bicycle use"